# Show all result with more then 1 entry

Tags: mysql, sql

Suppose this is the result of a query

```
  id            value
------        ---------
  10              123
  10              422
  11              441
  11              986
  12              674
  13              648
```

What do i need to add to the query to return all the id's which have 2 or more values associated with them. So, in that case it will only return ID 10 & 11, but i need al the records.

so the result looks like:

```
 id            value
------        ---------
  10              123
  10              422
  11              441
  11              986
```

GROUP BY won't help me because i got only 1 back.. ;-)

Thank you.

Answer (score 1):

Here is a simple way to do this

```
select * from table where id in (select id from table group by id having count(id)>1) order by id;
```

Comment: Should be `IN`...

Comment: @Prdp Thank you , I forgot that "=" would cause errors when multiple rows are returned by the subquery. Corrected it likewise.

Comment: For some reason that `count(id)>=2` is not pleasing to my eyes. I would write it as `Count(id)>1` ;)

Comment: That certainly is a much more cleaner way, edited likewise.

Comment: You deserve +1 ;)

Answer (score 0):

You can use `exists`:

```
select t.*
from t
where exists (select 1 from t t2 where t2.id = t.id and t2.value <> t.value);
```